# What is causing a JVMTI_ERROR_NULL_POINTER?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm getting an error when my application starts.  It appears to be after it's initialized its connection to the database.  It also may be when it starts to spawn threads, but I haven't been able to cause it to happen on purpose.

The entire error message is:
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP NewGlobalRef, jvmtiError=JVMTI_ERROR_NULL_POINTER(100)
JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_NULL_POINTER(100): NewGlobalRef

erickson:
I'm not very familiar with the DB code, but hopefully this string is helpful:
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databasename=FOO

Tom Hawtin:
It's likely I was only getting this error when debugging, but it wasn't consistent enough for me to notice.

Also, I fixed a bug that was causing multiple threads to attempt to update the same row in DB and I haven't gotten the JVMTI... error since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JVMTI is the debugging and profiling protocol. So, I'm guessint it's something peculiar to the environment you are attempting to run your application in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using a native-code–based database driver (JDBC driver type 1 or 2). And I'm guessing that driver is buggy. If you could provide more information about the driver and your datasource configuration or connection string, it might help determine some answers.