# what causes this error - JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NULL_POINTER(201)

Tags: java

The server is automatically getting closed after throwing this error.

```
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NULL_POINTER(201): NewGlobalRef [../../../src/share/back/util.c:46]
The application has requested the JVM to exit with an fatal error from JNI. Error message:
JDWP NewGlobalRef, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_NULL_POINTER(201)
```

Can anybody help me with this..

Comment: It might help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343/what-is-causing-a-jvmti-error-null-pointer?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343/what-is-causing-a-jvmti-error-null-pointer?rq=1)

Comment: I have already checked that, it didn't helped me.

Comment: Can you throw some more light on your problem

Comment: while debugging the application in middle its throwing the error and the server is getting closed. And some times starting point itself server is getting closed with this error. And some times the debugging goes fine.

Comment: don't know when this error will be thrown...but its giving me so much trouble.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?